# C++ Segmentation Fault (core dump) when Using dynamic 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, dynamic-arrays, coredump

For an assignment, I need to be able to multiply user inputted matrices. To hold the matrices, I'm using 2D `arrays`, their `sizes` inputted by the user. I initialize the size and create the `array` as follows:

note, I'm trying to use `short` to limit the amount of `memory` used on the values (test values won't likely be large).

In the `source` file, a `constructor` (the default constructor looks identical except no `parameters` and `rows/cols` are initialized to `1`).

Header File :

```
short int** value_array;
```

Source File :

```
 Matrix::Matrix(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
 {
    rows = x;
    cols = y;
    value_array = NULL;
    value_array = new short int*[rows];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        value_array[i] = new short int[cols];
 }
```

In the initializing `function` :

```
void Matrix::init(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, short int value)
{
     value_array[x][y] = value;
     return;
}
```

The `destructor` looks like this :

```
Matrix::~Matrix()   // destructor
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        delete value_array[i];
    delete [] value_array;
}
```

In the `main.cpp` file, the only pointer-related `code` is calling these `functions`. The `value_array` is a `private-variable`.

The `core dump` happens either when the `matrix` is being initialized or (if it's small) when the `matrix` containing the product after multiplication is created, which leads me to think it's somewhere in the creation code.

I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04`, running this in terminal with the `g++` `compiler`.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please. Also step through your program with the debugger to narrow the source of your error, before doing so.

Comment: BTW `delete value_array[i];` is supposed to be `delete[] value_array[i];` and the code you provide is not complete for the question you are asking.

Comment: Why not use the containers c++ provides for you instead of  `**` stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is in the loop you use in the `Matrix` constructor.  You're looping over the `cols` value and not `rows`.

What ends up happening is that in your `Matrix` destructor, you loop over the rows in the inner loop, and doing so results in calling `delete` on rows that may not exist.

[Live Example of Bug](http://ideone.com/h1xeTd)

Therefore this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < cols; i++) 
    value_array[i] = new short int[cols];
```

Should be:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
    value_array[i] = new short int[cols];
```

In addition in your destructor, this:

```
delete value_array[i];
```

Should be:

```
delete [] value_array[i];
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I kinda figured it was something like that, I guess I just needed an extra set of eyes. IOU one PaulMcKenzie